expo-camera não grava vídeo para Android
Estou usando a versão 51 do Expo Go para executar minha aplicação react-native versão 0.74.5. O objetivo é simples, é gravar um vídeo curto de 5 segundos e exibir o log na tela em caso de sucesso. A biblioteca expo-camera versão 15.0.16 usada para isso funciona muito bem para IOS porém no Android o vídeo não é gravado, não ocorre nenhum erro, apenas a função da biblioteca expo-camera, recordAsync, não retorna nada. O problema não é com as permissões de uso da câmera, todas elas foram atribuídas corretamente. E acredito que as permissões de uso de aúdio e microfone também não são necessárias já que defino mute={true} dentro do meu componente.
Seque a função takeVideo:
const takeVideo = async () =>{
setButtonVisible(false); // Oculta o botão imediatamente ao clicar
const cameraInstance = cameraRef.current;

if (cameraInstance) {
  try {
    console.log('Tentando gravar vídeo...');
    // Inicia a gravação do vídeo
    const video = await cameraInstance.recordAsync({
      maxDuration: 5
    });
    console.log(video);
    if (video?.uri) {
      const videoUri = video.uri;
      setCapturedVideo(videoUri); // Armazena o URI do vídeo no estado
      setMessage('Imagem capturada com sucesso!');
      setIsError(false);
    } else {
      setMessage('Erro ao capturar imagem!');
      setIsError(true);
      console.log('Falha ao gravar o vídeo.');
    }

  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Erro ao gravar vídeo:', error);
    setMessage('Erro ao capturar imagem!');
    setIsError(true);
  } finally {
    cameraInstance.stopRecording(); // Para a gravação
    setCameraVisible(false); // Fecha o modal da câmera após 5 segundos
    console.log('Vídeo Gravado com sucesso!');
  }
} else {
  setMessage('Erro ao tentar abrir a câmera');
  setIsError(true);
  console.error('Referência da câmera não encontrada.');
}

Segue o componente CameraView:
<CameraView ref={cameraRef} style={styles.camera} facing='front' mode='video' mute={true} videoQuality='720p'>

          {/* Oval central para guiar o rosto */}
          <View style={styles.ovalContainer}>
            <View style={styles.oval}></View>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            {buttonVisible && ( // Só exibe o botão se 'buttonVisible' for true
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={takeVideo}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Iniciar</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
          </View>
        </CameraView>

No caso a mensagem exibida pelo log no Android é 'Tentando gravar vídeo...' e não recebe uma resposta. Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço.
